# How to get rid of SIGTERM error

Tags: iphone, xcode4, program-entry-point, sigterm

i have been working on this iphone app in the new xcode4. Practically every time I exit my application in the simulator I get an error on a code line in the main.m Here is my line of code, and then the error on the next line

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGTERM".

What is happening here? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SIGTERM is a Unix signal, used to tell your program to quit (TERMinate). When you run your program in Xcode, it runs it within gdb, the debugger program, which automatically catches certain signals. The signal handling behaviour of gdb can be controller but I'm just now myself researching how it's done so can't give you details. In the past, applications on Mac OS or iPhone were sent Apple Quit events, I think, but the SIGTERM signal may be used by the sudden termination feature recently added.

Comment: Info about gdb signals support (easily found on Google): [gdb signals](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gdb-5.0/html_node/gdb_38.html) - This is one of many mirrors.