# What is this error in Ruby? Signal Exception SIGTERM

Tags: ruby

I have been doing some tutorials on Ruby, and while running some sample code I received the following error:

Error executing code -
Signal Exception -
SIGTERM

I am wondering what causes this error to occur. I read that, "SIGTERM is a Unix signal, used to tell your program to quit (TERMinate)." But I'm curious as to what you cause this error if I was coding on my own?

link to quote: [How to get rid of SIGTERM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691501/how-to-get-rid-of-sigterm-error)

Comment: Some monitoring processes could in theory send a TERM to another process if they  detected that it was mis-behaving, or it could be used in a dev environment to manage child processes. Also Ruby can send a TERM itself using the `Process` module. You may need to give more context: Does the TERM always occur, can you reproduce that in a few lines of code and post it here?

Comment: I wish I could but it's literally just a string concatenation example where the sample code is:

`'Ruby' + 'Monk'`

with a built in compiler on the site.

Comment: Probably the on-site controlling process thinks there is a problem. It will likely have some strict controls to prevent long-running processes, unexpected IO and that will include sending TERM processes that take longer than expected to complete, even if that's not the fault of any code you write. If it seems inexplicable, you should contact the site owners.

Comment: @PalmfrondJohn are you still having the issue?