# What does "Thread 1: signal SIGTERM" mean in xcode with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, signals

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "XYZAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([XYZAppDelegate class]));
    } 
}
```

The program works fine and I'm just curious about the case. The notification pointed at the 7th line and I could drag it among lines when I do so, a warning showed up warns me the moving of instruction pointer may cause serious problems. So, what's the instruction pointer? Can it disappear?

I really have few programming experiences and I just pick up the iOS programming these days, I hardly know what thread is and I found that `SIGTERM` is one of the Unix signals which seemed come from nowhere as for me. How does it work? I looked it up in the wiki and found some signals like `SIGABRT` have similar functions as `SIGTERM`, what's the difference?

I will truly appreciate your patience if you can solve the problems for a novice like me.

PS: I found it disappears when I quit `xcode` and reentry it.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please make sure you have read all related documentations, search, researched and read all previously-asked questions before asking a new one. Your question has been asked several times before and has an answer. As an instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691501/how-to-get-rid-of-sigterm-error

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much this is a simple bug in Xcode. It seems to just go away whenever Xcode is closed and then reopened.

restart Xcode.

if persistent : click out of the folder you are in, and proceed to your view controller and it should disappear.

hit command S and save and update all of your views, models, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Ezra says, I believe is a simple bug in Xcode.

Try this:

When you open "The Simulator" don't close it by clicking on red X (as usual) instead close the simulator by pressing "**command + Q**" and that error won't appear again.

That's worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Checking Xcode 14, when closing the window it displays the "Thread" message in the code.

If you quit the Simulator.app, it logs "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15" in the Debug Log.